# Не изменяется css с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Вот страница здесь идёт проверка существования куки, если куков нет, то должен выводиться блок с текстом сейчас этот блок скрыт, но при нажатии должен появляться с помощью jquery. Блок не выводиться что не правильно?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.cookie('name', 'Тимур', {
      expires: 30
  });

  var test = $.cookie('name');

  if (test) {

  $('#name').css('display', 'block');
  }else{
  }
    </script>
    <style media="screen">
    .hello1 {
      background: #000;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.7;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 100;
      display: none;
    }
    .hello {
      background-color:#FFFFFF;
      height: 200px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 100px;
      left: 40%;
      color: #000000;
      width: 300px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HEllo</h1>
      <h1>HEllo</h1>
        <h1>HEllo</h1>
          <h1>HEllo</h1>

            <h1>HEllo</h1>
              <h1>HEllo</h1>
                <h1>HEllo</h1>
                  <h1>HEllo</h1>  <h1>HEllo</h1>
                    <h1>HEllo</h1>
                      <h1>HEllo</h1>

                        <h1>HEllo</h1>  <h1>HEllo</h1>

                          <h1>HEllo</h1>
    <div class="hello1" id="name">
      <div class="hello" id="popup">
        <p>Текст в окне</p>
      </div>
 </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А вообще-то, более одного `<h1>` тега на странице быть не должно

Comment: Это для примера вместо этого будет записи

Comment: Для примера - нужно делать нормальный пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (test) {
  // Здесь элемента с id="name" еще нет.
  $(function(){
    // А здесь - уже есть.
    $('#name').css('display', 'block');
  });
}else{
}
```

И, конечно, библиотека jQuery должна быть вставлена в страницу выше Вашего тэга `script`.